# Get the names from individual tables using a common id table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables :

```
1. Boy (id, Name, Address)     
2. Girl (id, Name, Address)    
3. Couples (Boy_id, Girl_id)
```

The tables Boy and Girl has the name and personal details of all the boys and girls in a school.

Now the third table is the list of couples in that school, which has the id of the boy and girl from the Boy and Girl table.

I want to get the list of couples with their names in the output and not the ids.

```
Output (Boy.Name, Girl.Name)
```

I have tried using the following query, but it gives me a very large output :

```
SELECT  
  Boy.Name, Girl.Name 
FROM   
  Boy, Girl, Couples 
WHERE   
  Boy.id = Couples.Boy_id AND Girl.id = Couples.Girl_id
```

Can anyone please point out the mistake in this query and provide me the correct one?

Comment: Your query works for me, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1ca9/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases you have to use `JOIN`s to get data.

```
SELECT b.name, g.name
FROM Couples c
LEFT JOIN Boy b ON (b.id = c.Boy_id)
LEFT JOIN Girl g ON (g.id = c.Girl_id)
```

Comment: This query gives the same result as my query

Comment: @user2877208 Good, that's how it should work :) It returns all couples names in two fields.

Comment: I am using Postgresql, and these tables are just an illustration of actual tables. In my original tables (which are clinical data from my research) i have 357 entries in Boy table, 437 in Girls and 990 in Couples. The result that i get using these queries has 8019000 rows.

Comment: You should use INNER JOIN, not LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @user2877208 You've got much more couples than actual people?

Comment: These tables are just an illustration of my actual data. The schema is the same, but the actual tables have my research data. So in this example we can consider that a boy can date several girls and girl can date several boys

Comment: @user2877208 When using `LEFT` or `INNER` join you can't receive more results than there is in main table (`Couples` in that case). Are you sure you checked this query?

Comment: @ElonThan I used the exact same query that you mentioned above, still i am getting 8019000 rows. I have numerous repetitions of the same entries in the result

Comment: @ElonThan Problem Solved. I had accidentally created duplicates in the Boy and Girl tables while testing some code out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.name, g.name FROM Couples c 
INNER JOIN Boy b ON c.Boy_id=b.id 
INNER JOIN Girl g ON c.Girl_id=g.id;
```